# Can I customize keyboard layout for apple tv?

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I want to have a custom keyboard (without full-screen keyboard) instead of default keyboard in my apple tv app?

If possible, what are the approaches should I follow?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [SearchTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/SearchTemplate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH33-SW1) is the only keyboard available for TVML, and there isn't a whole lot you can do with it.

But with TVML, there's 2 ways you can do redo the keyboard

1) using [section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/CoumpoundDisplayElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH18-SW26) with `lockup` and some TVJS, to create your own keyboard. Each lockup can be a character and onclick, can trigger tvjs to record and display the character into a label. Should be relative easy to implement, specially if you are only dealing with a small set of characters, like numbers.

2) [custom element](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/CreatingYourOwnClassesandElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016718-CH23-SW10), as described in the docs, you can use native code to define any element and.. you can make your own keyboard that way.

=-=-=-=-=-=

**Update**

Somehow I missed the [form template.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/FormTemplate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH29-SW1) This template included a keyboard too. And, you can *customize this keyboard!

The [textField](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/SimpleMultimediaElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH20-SW6) element provides a field for users to enter text, which also accepts [the keyboardType attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/TVJSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH42-SW1) for selecting the type of keyboard to display. It even has support for number and URL inputs.

(*basic customization lol)

Comment: Is there any chance of rejecting the app if I customise the keyboard?

Comment: I think if your use case makes sense, and improve the user experience without going too far away from the apple standard (or too crazy), but staying within the apple template is always the safest

Comment: @RamaChandraMahapatra, just found out you can use the form template to customize the keyboard to a certain degree.